# How does the formal definition of limit deal with functions that are not defined at multiple points, maybe even entire intervals?

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

So the formal definition:

$(\forall \epsilon > 0)(\exists \delta > 0)(\forall x \in \mathbb{R})(0 < \mid x - x_0 \mid < \delta \implies \mid f(x) - L \mid < \epsilon)$

If this is true then we say $\lim_{x \to x_0} f(x) = L$. In my opinion, this really only makes sense if the function is defined for all values of $\mathbb{R} - \{x_0\}$. Say the function is not defined at a point different from $x_0$, call it $x_1$, then the expression  $\mid f(x_1) - L \mid < \epsilon$ doesn't make sense and we can't really assign a truth value to it, and so we can't really know if a specific $\delta$ that includes $x_1$ is good or not.

I thought about it and came up with two possible solutions, but I have my doubts about both. First we could modify the definition of limit so that it only works for values where the function is defined, for instance if $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and the function is defined as $f:A \to\mathbb{R}$, we could tweak the formal definition so that it says:

$(\forall \epsilon > 0)(\exists \delta > 0)(\forall x \in A)(0 < \mid x - x_0 \mid < \delta \implies \mid f(x) - L \mid < \epsilon)$

This solution has a problem and the problem is that if a function is only defined at one point, call it $x_0$, then the limit as $x$ approaches $x_0$ would exist because the implication would always be vacuously true, but we don't want the limit to exist in such cases.

The second solution, which I think is the more natural one, is to define $\mid f(x) - L \mid < \epsilon$ as false when $f(x)$ is not defined for that specific value of $x$. This solution has the side effect that in order for the limit to be defined at a point $x_0$, the function would have to be defined on an open interval that contains $x_0$, with the possible exception of $x_0$ itself. The problem with that is that I was arguing with someone about it and they told me the limit should exist even when the function is not defined on one side of $x_0$, as long as it is defined on the other side.

So what is it then? How do you deal with functions that are not defined in points other than $x_0$?

Answer (score 2):

For us to talk about the limit of $f$ at $x_0$, we require $x_0$ to be an accumulation point of the domain of $f$, that is, that for every $c>0$ there is some $x\in \operatorname{Dom}(f)$, with $x\neq x_0$, in $(x_0-c,x_0+c)$.

This is equivalent to saying that there exists a sequence in the domain of $f$ that converges to $x_0$ but is never actually equal to $x_0$.

In other case, $x_0$ is called an isolated point (of the domain) and it does not make sense to talk about the limit of $f$ at $x_0$.

Comment: OK, so I imagine that means if we have a function defined at $[2, 3]$ and nothing else and we want the limit at $3$, by your definition $3$ is an accumulation point, right? So the limit could exist in that case. But by my second interpretation it cannot exist since it's not defined on an open interval that contains $3$. How exactly do you make sense of the expression $\mid f(x) - L \mid < \epsilon$ when $f(x)$ is not defined? What is its truth value?

Comment: The limit at $3$ could perfectly exist. We do **not** need $f$ to be defined at an open interval around $3$. In your formal definition of limit, you need to force both $x\in \operatorname{Dom}(f)$ and $0<|x-x_0|<\delta$.

Comment: But the problem with doing that is that it would be equivalent to my first interpretation and that has the problem that limit would exist even if $x_0$ is not an accumulation point, for instance, the limit would exist if the function is only defined at one point. Consider a function only defined at $x_0$, then $x \in Dom(f) \text{ and } 0 < \mid x - x_0 \mid < \delta$ would be false for all values of $x$ and $\delta$, thus $(x \in Dom(f) \text{ and } 0 < \mid x - x_0 \mid < \delta) \implies (\mid f(x) - L \mid < \epsilon)$  would be true for all $\epsilon$, the limit would exist.

Comment: The definition requires $x_0$ to be an accumulation point. If it isn't, there's nothing to talk about.

Comment: I see, then the right approach would be my first interpretation of only checking values of $x$ that are in the domain, as well as specifying that $x_0$ must be an accumulation point. I decided to double check if this was the case in the book Mathematical Analysis by Zorich and seems that this is exactly what he does, but he uses the concept of a limit point, is that the same or equivalent to an accumulation point?

Comment: Yes, a limit point is the same as an accumulation point.